# How to switch between address port in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, port

In a Node.js application, I'm listening to two ports on the localhost like down below:

```
const express = require('express');
app = express();

function startServer(port, hostname, app) {

    app.get('/', (req, res) => {
      res.send(`Welcome on server ${hostname} on port ${port}`);
    });

    app.listen(port, hostname);
    console.log(`listening ${hostname} on port ${port}`);
};

function startServerRedirect(port, hostname, app) {

    app.get('/', (req, res) => {

      res.send(`running server on ${hostname} on port ${port}`);
      res.redirect('localhost:4000');
    });

    app.listen(port, hostname);
    console.log(`listening ${hostname} on port ${port}`);
};

var hostname = '127.0.0.1';
startServerRedirect(3000, hostname, app);
startServer(4000, hostname, app);
```

I had problem to run first server on default 80 port, but it doesn't matter. I want to be able to send the user on another server port and display him/her other content. It's important for me to do it this way rather than `app.route` or something.

Comment: You cant start your server on port 80. what's your problem I didn't understand please tell with more description.

Comment: I think he wants to redirect user on another server port during runtime of his nodejs instance.

Comment: you don't want to call `res.send` and then `res.redirect`. Maybe replace `res.send` with `console.log`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
const port = process.env.PORT || 80 ;
```

Answer (score 0):

For this setup to work, you need to change a couple things.

First, you'll need two separate express apps, one to handle the redirects and the other to receive them. i.e. the 2 different ports.

```
const app1 = express()
const app2 = express()
```

Then of course at the end you would pass them to your helper functions:

```
startServerRedirect(3000, hostname, app1);
startServer(4000, hostname, app2);
```

Also, in your call to `redirect`, make sure you use the full url with "http://" in this case, `http://localhost:4000`

Finally, you don't want to call `res.send` before `res.redirect`. The reason is `res.send` kicks off a response, but `res.redirect` sets http headers. And any http headers you set need to be done first. So here since it's just informational you can use a `console.log` instead if you want to inspect how the app works:

```
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  console.log(`running server redirect on ${hostname} on port ${port}`);
  res.redirect('http://localhost:4000');
});
```

That goes in `startServerRedirect`

As far as port 80, I believe you need root access to run there, but that's another issue... (nginx proxy?)